# Volume Change comparitors

Tags: stock-markets, trading-volume, statistics

I've put together a little market addin for excel and have been asked by the person commissioning the plugin to add the Volume Change for the last minute. That was easy enough using my API (alphavantage), but they now want that number displayed as a percentage, which AV doesn't offer.

I don't know WHAT to compare the last minute Volume to. Currently I'm comparing it to the current trading volume (minuteVolume/currentVolume)*100, I feel that number could possible prove to be a false indicator, since the current Volume will update every 10 seconds (my code loops in 10 sec intervals) - causing the volumeChange % to decrease/increase artificially depending on the direction of change. Eventually it catches up, but for about 5 cycles it slowly decreases as the currentVolume increases.

I'm not very market savvy, so I'm kind of at a loss as to what to use for the divisor in the equation: (minuteVolume/x)*100 in order to achieve a more accurate representation of the percent change in volume. Last month's total volume? Last week's volume? Month to date total volume? I need a divisor that isn't going to just change every 10 seconds.

Comment: Have you asked your client about what kind of volume they are wanting to compare to?

Comment: Yes - not very helpful. Client claimed he used some charts a while back that gave him that number in percentage form- he's an old school day-trader, but the actual math behind the scenes isn't really his thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider on balance volume (OBV) - as an indicator, it's fairly predictive.

see http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/onbalancevolume.asp

pretty easy to calculate.

Comment: Looks good. Stable number that my API can pull each minute in conjunction with minuteVolume. Thanks!